# I want to range the nodes by degree - why is this Neo4J Cypher request so slow?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to first get all the nodes of a certain type connected to a context and then simply range them by their degree, but only for the (:TO) type of connection to the other nodes that belong to the same context. I tried several ways including the ones below but they are too slow (10s of seconds). Is there any way to make it faster?

```
MATCH (ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'})<-[:AT]-(c1:Concept) 
WITH c1 MATCH (c1)-[r:TO]-(c2:Concept) 
WHERE r.context = '60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb' 
RETURN c2, count(r) as degree ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 10;
```

```
MATCH (ctx:Context{uid:'60156a60-d3e1-11ea-9477-f71401ca7fdb'})<-[:AT]-(c1:Concept)-[:TO]-(c2:Concept) 
RETURN c1, count(c2) as degree 
ORDER BY degree DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Can you add an expanded PROFILE plan of the query?

Answer (score 0):

One way to examine degree is using the size function, have you tried something like this?

```
 size((c1)-[:TO]-(:Concept))
```

In my graph size() appears to be more efficient, but it might be my cypher rearrangement as well.

Example: (in my graph) This statement is 81db hits

```
PROFILE MATCH (g:Gene {name:'ACE2'})-[r:EXPRESSED_IN]-(a)
return  count(r)
```

And this is 4 db hits

```
PROFILE MATCH (g:Gene {name:'ACE2'})
return size((g)-[:EXPRESSED_IN]-())
```

I'm not sure this next suggestion is faster/more efficient, but if you always calculate degree on a single or subset of relationships, you might look into storing the degree values just to see if that might be an option (faster?).

I do this on my entire graph right after a bulk load

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (n) return n",
"set n.degree = size((n)--())",
{batchSize:50000, batchMode: "BATCH", parallel:true});
```

but for a different reason, I want to see the degree value in the neo4j browser (for example...) Note: I rebuilt my graphs daily from the ground up but then it is static until the next rebuild